# Checking Char input from command line argument

Tags: c

I have to take an input from command line argument. If the argument is invalid it will print an error message and exit. But whatever argument I am giving it is always producing error message. Even if I give the right argument. I don't know whats wrong.

```
if (argv[1][0] !='a' || arg[1][0] !='m') { 
  printf("Error: Invalid arguments!\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (which includes a function `main`). What is `arg`? Do you mean `argv`?

Comment: `!= 'a' ||` Did you mean `&&` maybe? Any character is different from at least one of `'a'` or `'m'`.

Comment: Please provide us the full code including how you are accepting the answer and what are these variables

Comment: There are some C libraries that handle a lot of this stuff for you, though they might take a little time to learn. You can search github, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arg[1][0]` is not valid. use `argv[1][0]`.

```
void printError(){
     printf("Invalid Parameter\n");
     exit(-1);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv){
    if(argc < 2) 
         printError();
    switch(argv[1][0]){
         case 'a': // your code
                  break;
         case 'm': // your code
                  break;
         default:
                 printError();
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect "arg" was just a typo on the OP's part.  I also suspect he wasn't checking "argc" (like you clearly do in your example).  I hope your response helps him :)